# $F_q$ is a finite field. Then $F_q^\star\not\cong (Z_m)^\star$ for any $m$ with $[F_q:F_p]\geq 2$ and $(Z_m)^\star\to F_q^\star$ cannot be surjection

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $q=p^a$. Denote $F_q$ the finite field with $q$ elements. Denote $R^\star$ as the invertible elements of ring $R$.

Then $F_q^\star\not\cong (Z_m)^\star$ if $[F_q:F_p]\geq 2$. Note that this asserts abelian multiplicative group structure non-isomorphism. There is no guarantee additive structures are compatible here.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Since $F_q^\star$ is cyclic, it suffices to show $(Z_m)^\star$ will never have cardinality $p^a-1$. $Z_m^\star$ is cyclic iff $m=2, 4, 2q^b, q^b$ where $q$ is a prime number. I have ruled out $m=2,4$ case which are trivial. I have only $m=q^b$ case remaining. This amounts to assert $q^{b-1}(q-1)=p^a-1$ admitting no solution to $q$ prime and $b$ with $a\geq 2$ for any odd prime $p$. Any hint on how to proceed will be sufficient?

Context: This is related to an assertion made in Washington, Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields. Chpt 6, Sec 1. "$\chi:F_q^\star\to C^\star$ is never a Dirichlet character unless $q=p$. Hence I need to see $F_q^\star\not\cong (Z_m)^\star$ as Dirichlet characters starts from $(Z_m)^\star$. It seems this is supposed to be obvious. Have I thought something too complicated here?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Do I know any character of $F_q^\star$ cannot be embedded into characters of $(Z_m)^\star$ for any $m$? In other words, I should never have a surjection map $Z_m^\star\to F_q^\star$.

Comment: It is easy to see that $a$ cannot be even, but I don't see how to extend it. If $a=2c$ then $$q^{b-1}(q-1)=(p^c-1)(p^c+1)$$ and $gcd(p^c-1,p^c+1)=2$. this shows that $q^{b-1}$ must divide one of $p^c-1$ or $p^c+1$, which makes it much larger than the other term for $b > 2$... The case $b=2$is easy to check..

Comment: $19^1\left(19-1\right) = 7^3-1$, so I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, it seems that I am out of luck by looking at the cardinality. I was hoping that if $F_q^\star\cong (Z_m)^\star$, I can produce at least 2 non-trivial odd divisors of $q-1$ or $4\mid q-1$ which gives me desired contradiction. Then I do not see why the book says $\chi:F_q^\star\to C^\star$ can never be a Dirichlet character unless $p=q$. It seems that this part is meant to be easy as there was no comment on this as well.

Comment: I think the equal cardinalities mean that the groups are isomorphic -- after all, they're both cyclic ($19^2$ is an odd prime power). Maybe Washington meant to say "it is not a Dirichlet character *in general*"? I can't find this specific claim in my Washington.

Comment: @darijgrinberg. The original text says, "If $q\neq p$, such characters are not the Dirichlet characters studied earlier." Such characters means multiplicative characters $F_q^\star\to C^\star$.

Comment: I think he implicitly means "in general". Anyway, forget about this unless he actually *uses* the non-equality anywhere.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It on the page right before Lemma 6.1 and before definition of gauss sums.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Does washington also mean in general it cannot come from a character restriction from $(Z_m)^\star$ as well? He implicitly implies that conductor will not come into the discussion.

Comment: I don't know -- where does he say it, and what map is the restriction induced by?

Comment: @darijgrinberg "If $q\neq p$, such characters are not the Dirichlet
characters studied earlier. The concept of conductor will not enter into the
present discussion." It is still on the page above Lemma 6.1 Since in your example, there is definitely identification of characters and I can totally have characters for any $Z_n\to Z_m$ surjection inducing multiplicative group surjection. Then I can take the dual to induce the restriction map.

Comment: From what I understand, Dirichlet characters are just (arbitrary multiplicative) characters of a group of the form $Z_m^\times$. Thus, if you identify $Z_{19^2}^\times$ with $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}^\times$, then the Dirichlet characters of the former *are* the multiplicative characters of the latter.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for clarification.